# How to fix the tree structure for a tree-based algorithm?

Tags: boosting, cart, algorithms, lightgbm

*Background*

Some of our BI analysts and most of our managers are interested in making explainable predictions. One of our colleagues proposed an approach based on individual tree leaves from a tree-based algorithm (that we also use as black box predictors). Preference for a collection of explicitly defined tree leaves over an unobservable ensemble of many such leaves (i.e. a tree-based model) is motivated by explainability and traditional century-old insurance industry methods of discovering data clusterings with higher average target values (typically some risk measures).

*Problems*

The main difficulty is how to use data partitioning information from *more than a single tree*, utilizing benefits of ensembling and cross-validation. Note that in practice tree structure tends to differ between all trees in the ensemble (such as boosting rounds in a GBDT algo) and between all cross-validation folds, so a leaf data usually cannot be averaged from multiple trees, because every leaf in every tree by default is unique.

*Options*

One approach would be such a set of hyperparameters that would ensure fixed tree structure for all trees in the ensemble, another: re-using the same pre-trained tree-based model object across all cross-validation folds or members of an ensemble, and yet another - a modified `predict` function that would keep a tree structure intact (ideally also with unchanged split points).

Comment: This will provide no benefit. The wikipedia article on ensemble learning theory says "Empirically, ensembles tend to yield better results when there is a significant diversity among the models." By specifying the tree structure you'll essentially be creating copies of the same model.

Comment: @RyanVolpi yes, I realize it defeats the purpose of ensembling (by forgoing variance reduction), but there are other significant benefits from those tree-based models: 1) built-in cross-validation and 2) computational speed. I think the models should be forced to specialize to just 1 tree to get the above benefits without distorting predictions (in contrast to picking 1 tree from the ensemble, e.g. with `lgbm.create_tree_digraph`)?